# Info on Apache's code 302, where does it redirect to?

Tags: apache-http-server

I'm running a LAMP system (on a Pi) and I get a lot of mischievous requests which seem to result in a 302 status code, like:

> 140.143.16.158 - - [06/Mar/2020:18:32:32 +0100] "GET /TP/public/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 540 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0;en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6)"

As I understand it, my Apache webserver indicates a temporary redirect. But where does it redirect to? I just don't know how my webserver handles this (correctly ??) and I don't know where or what to check .. Can somebody explain?
Whatever is needed to solve this question will be provided. For instance, here's my  *000-default.conf* (comments left out):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule .*   https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I think I figured it out .. For those interested:

The rewrite rule was put in place as a permanent redirect from http to https, so I was expecting a 301 code (permanent redirect). But it turns out when only using [R], Apache issues a 302 (temporary redirect) not a 301.

It was the 'temporary' part that confused me. I changed the rewriterule flags to [R=301,L] (BTW, L stands for *last rule to process*). I'll be monitoring my access log to see if I'm right.

Comment: Maybe useful for other newbies like me: monitor effectively / see the chain of events: tail -f /var/log/apache2/{access,error}.log